# Можно ли сделать авторизация на сайте через youtube с помощью django-allauth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Можно ли как-то сделать авторизация на сайте через [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/) с помощью [`django-allauth`](https://pypi.org/project/django-allauth/)?

Comment: Разве это так работает? Ведь на `YouTube` авторизация через аккаунт `Google`. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: На `Google` аккаунте может быть несколько `YouTube` каналов

Answer (score 0):

Открываем *[документацию](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html)* - смотрим список провайдеров. `Youtube` там нет - значит, нельзя.

Comment: Не знаешь через что можно?

Comment: Не знаю, можно ли это вообще реализовать.